# AppCompatActivity - class not Found for any Activity that extends AppCompatActivity

Tags: android

Everything compiles fine but at runtime for any activity that extends

```
  MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
```

This activity cannot be found at runtime.  MainActivity cannot be found. It says nothing about not finding AppCompatActivity

Very weird. I have never in 5 years of Android programming not been able to find class for Activity at runtime? How can this be?

All other activities that do not extend AppCompatActivity are found.  What's going on here?

```
  10-28 16:27:09.289: E/AndroidRuntime(12471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mycomp.locker/com.mycomp.locker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycomp.locker.MainActivity
```

So immediatley for MainActivity.  If I leave MainActivity as regular activity then it will launch but crash the moment I try to create an intent for that Activity that extends AppCompatActivity:

```
Intent  i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, CompatExtendingActivity.class);
```

/// crash right here same way.

It's a maven build, after Maven SDK Deployer ...

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>23.1.0</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v7-appcompat</artifactId>
        <version>23.1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>23.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>6.0_r1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
```

Now why am I using AppCompatActivity at all?  Because I wanted to use a widget SwitchCompat.  When I used this component in an ordinary activity I got another error that it could not find:

```
  android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager$ColorFilterLruCache
```

So I backed off using regular Activity.  Looking inside the jar for compat-v7 I do see this class however. I have tried with compile and provided options in maven but neither makes a difference.

Android-Manifest:

```
  package="com.mycomp.locker" 
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
```

I changed nothing here.  All I did was have MainActivity extend AppCompatActivity

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Post your error log also

Comment: Can open your `MainActivity` with **Ctrl** + **click**? This is to ensure that it is linking to the correct file.

Comment: change the scope of support lib dependency?

Comment: post Manifest full code

Comment: @Heisenberg  tried that. Did not make difference. The strange thing is that is is not saying it cannot find the base class. Its saying it cannot find the derived Activity at runtime ... I'm thinking maybe wrong version of compatibility lib vs. sdk version?

Comment: I have run into similar issue, I just deleted the .m2 folder and force updated dependencies. Maybe try that? And install support lib version 23.1.0 using SDK manager as well.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of error occurs after you change a package name.Go to your manifest file and make sure your activity is correctly referenced:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".BaseActivity" //Check here
        ...
    </activity>
```

As you can see from your edit, you have a package declared in your manifest as:

```
 package="com.mycompany.locker"
```

meanwhile, your activity's package is:

```
com.mycomp.locker.MainActivity
```

That's the cause of your problem, I think.

Comment: I don't think that it. I have posted my manifest above. I did not change the manifest at all. only the class I extended from changed. I did not change any package names. If in the code I Switch back to extend from Activity no problems.  Its all related to the code changes, and compat library.

Comment: No that's just an edit to keep out my companies name. There are no changes in the packagename or activity name.  I will update post

Comment: Hmm.Why isn't `Intent  i = new Intent(MainActivity.class, CompatExtendingActivity.class);` giving you a compile time error? Should be `MainActivity.this`

Comment: I just did that for example There is not compile time errors anywhere. it creates apk, but on starting up activity it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of your Intent.

Please add your Activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml.`

When you want to make a new activity, you should register it in your `AndroidManifest.xml.`

Comment: Its not a new activity. Its the same one, but extends a different base class.  Therefore its package name remains the same.

Comment: Can u use 'public class MainActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity'